# Error message: Unable to locate package libatlas3gf-base

Tags: python, scikit-learn, raspberry-pi3

I tried with the following commands to install scikit-learn package

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools 
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy 
sudo apt-get install libatlas-dev libatlas3gf-base
```

Got error message

```
Unable to locate package libatlas3gf-base
```

Comment: Have you tried using pip `sudo pip install numpy scipy` ?

Comment: Requirement already satisfied. Not sure what that libatlas-dev libatlas3gf-base is for.

Comment: Please don't post the answer to a question in the question body itself. You can post an answer to your own question detailing what solved the problem, and then you can accept your own answer 48 hours after the question was originally posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignore message, keep going with command

`pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=" -U scikit-learn`

'Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-options --install-options /global-options'. Takes forever to run setup.py install for scikit-learn, but finally installed.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the package that is much the same of what you have at hand.

```bash
$ apt-cache search libatlas
libatlas-base-dev - Automatically Tuned Linear Algebra Software, generic static
libatlas-cpp-0.6-3 - World Forge wire protocol library - runtime libs
libatlas-cpp-0.6-dev - World Forge wire protocol library - developer files
libatlas-cpp-0.6-tools - World Forge wire protocol library - tools
libatlas-cpp-doc - World Forge wire protocol library - documentation
libatlas-doc - Automatically Tuned Linear Algebra Software, documentation
libatlas-ecmwf-0 - Numerical weather prediction and climate modelling library
libatlas-ecmwf-dev - Numerical weather prediction and climate modelling library - dev files
libatlas-ecmwf-utils - Numerical weather prediction and climate modelling library - utilities
libatlas-test - Automatically Tuned Linear Algebra Software, test programs
libatlas3-base - Automatically Tuned Linear Algebra Software, generic shared
libblas-test - Basic Linear Algebra Subroutines 3, testing programs
libblas64-test - Basic Linear Algebra Subroutines 3, testing programs (64bit-index)
```

Gives me *libatlas3-base* as the nearest name. Taking that, the container could be built. As the other answer says it, leaving it out worked as well. This is more to show how you could find out about it when facing other package errors.